# laravel Can't delete old image when uploaded new image

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-8

why my old image can't be deleted when i uploaded new image?

this is my controller where i use to store data and image.
my file image name is stored  combination from **nama_post_adps** and from **$imageName** where that is query for `getClientOriginalName();`

```
  public function update(Request $request, Adopsi $adopsi, $id)
    {
        $getParentJenisHewan = JenisHewan::where("id", $request->jenis_hewan_id)->value("nama_jenis_hewan");
        $getParentRasHewan = RasHewan::where("id", $request->ras_hewan_id)->value("nama_ras_hewan");

        $imageSize = $request->file('image_post_adps')->getSize();
        $imageName = $request->file('image_post_adps')->getClientOriginalName();
        $pathstorage = $request->file('image_post_adps')->storeAs('public/post/adopsi',$request->nama_post_adopsi.'-'.$imageName);
       
        $adopsiAttr = $this->validasiRequest();
       
        $adopsiAttr = $request->all();
        $adopsiAttr['nama_jenis_hewan'] =  $getParentJenisHewan;
        $adopsiAttr['nama_ras_hewan'] = $getParentRasHewan;
        $adopsiAttr['image_post_adps'] = $imageName;
        $adopsiAttr['path-storage'] = $pathstorage;
        $adopsiAttr['size'] = $imageSize;
        
        $adopsi = Adopsi::find($id)->update($adopsiAttr);
        $delete = Adopsi::find($id);
        unlink('app/public/post/adopsi/'.$delete->nama_post_adopsi.'-'.$delete->image_post_adps);

        // if ($request->file('image_post_adps')) {
        //     Storage::disk('public')->delete('/post/adopsi/'.$request->nama_post_adopsi.'-'.$request->image_post_adps);
        // }

      

        if($adopsi) {
            return redirect()->route('adopsi.index')->with('success','Data '.$request->nama_post_adopsi .' telah mendapatkan update terbaru.');
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('adopsi.index')->with('error','Data gagal'.$request->nama_post_adopsi .'diupdate');

        }

    }
```

method above literally same with my **store** method .

i've try unlink() but it can't work and show  **error : unlink('post/adopsi/..') no such file or directory** , but field can't be updated. then i decided use `Storage::disk('public')->delete` , field got update, the image change with new but old still same.

Comment: \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::disk('public')->delete('post/adopsi/'.$delete->nama_post_adopsi.'-'.$delete->image_post_adps)

Comment: how can i simplify your suggestion?

Comment: i mean simplify the code

Comment: its the simplest code to delete file from storage folder

Comment: not that what i mean, how can i wrote without \Illuminate..... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing wrong.

First fetch existing data and check if request has file then delete old one then update it

```
        $delete = Adopsi::find($id);
     

         if ($request->file('image_post_adps')) {
             Storage::disk('public')->delete('/post/adopsi/'.$delete->nama_post_adopsi.'-'.$delete->image_post_adps);
       }

 $adopsi = Adopsi::find($id)->update($adopsiAttr);
```

Comment: thank you, it's work, so i have to fetch data first before delete, then i put my code update at the endd?

Comment: glad it that it helped you

Comment: thank you sir, i hope god always bless you and have a nice day ! :)